# How to Make Thumbnail of Post Stay Animated

Tags: php, images, uploads, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

When I upload my post with an animated .gif, the thumbnail generates into a new image and doesn't stay animated. It will stay animated inside the post which is great. It seems to resize the .gif image and convert it into a static image because it generates an image with the sizing at the end of the original file. Is there a code to add or remove that prevents it from generating a new image for the thumbnail so it just resizes down as the gif?

Comment: [According to this](http://cogdogblog.com/2013/11/20/dear-wordpress-i-know-you-can-resize-animated-gifs-but/), WP only likes certain files (or I didn't read it which is possible). The post also suggest installing an [external plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/animated-gif-resize/) but it looks older(ish). If you're inserting it into a post though, use the full sized (original) image instead of the WP resized version.

Comment: The old "Animated GIF resize" plugin seems to fail these days with Wordpress 4.x +  https://wordpress.org/plugins/animated-gif-resize/

Answer (score 1):

Actually WordPress render uploaded images. So if you upload a animated gif then it will not stay animated. Read this article on how to overcome these issue.

I haven't read it through but as Howdy_McGee said, you will have to use a plugin for that.

[Essential WordPress Plugins for Working With Animated GIFs](http://www.instantshift.com/2014/08/13/wordpress-gif-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter using `add_filter()` hook for `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` to teach Wordpress to resize animated gif images correctly:

```
/**
 * Filters the generated attachment meta data.
 * @param array $metadata An array of attachment meta data.
 * @param int $attachment_id Current attachment ID.
 * @param string $context Additional context. Can be 'create' when metadata was initially created for new attachment or 'update' when the metadata was updated.
 * @return array
 * @author: gresser 2020-11-26
 */
public function resizeGifs(array $metadata, int $attachment_id, string $context)
{
    if (preg_match('/\.gif$/', $metadata['file'])) {

        foreach ($metadata['sizes'] as $image_site) {

            $file_path_original = wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] .'/'. $metadata['file'];
            $imagick = new Imagick($file_path_original);
            $imagick = $imagick->coalesceImages();

            $width = $image_site['width'];
            $height = $image_site['height'];

            foreach ($imagick as $frame) {
                $frame->cropThumbnailImage($width, $height);
                $imagick->setImagePage($width, $height, 0, 0);
            }
            $imagick = $imagick->deconstructImages();

            $file_path_thump = wp_upload_dir()['path'] .'/'. $image_site['file'];
            $imagick->writeImages($file_path_thump, true);
        }
    }
    return $metadata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the message thumbnail animated, it is common to use the GIF format for the image. You can find a step-by-step guide on the internet on how to achieve this. As for creating a [deposit gif](https://blog.depositphotos.com/how-to-make-gifs-from-stock-videos.html) from a stock video, I was able to find a good article detailing how to do this. Keep in mind that some platforms may have file size limitations when uploading animated content such as GIFs, so check their guidelines if necessary.

Comment: Simply linking to another resource isn't good practice. Please stick to the standard and provide a comprehensive answer in the post, which is accessible in the future.  A link can be broken one day.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).